# Qt program deployment

Tags: qt, deployment

In one of my programs I use `QWebView` to load and print reports made from HTML documents. So while deployment I copy these libraries, in additional to all other relevant Qt libraries:

- Qt5WebKit.dll
- Qt5WebKitWidgets.dll
- Qt5PrintSupport.dll
- plugins/printsupport/windowsprintersupport.dll

After testing on destination machine I've found that printing doesn't work. Thanks for Dependency Walker I've get all the missed libraries. Here is the list:

- Qt5Multimedia.dll
- Qt5Positioning.dll
- Qt5MultimediaWidgets.dll
- Qt5Qml.dll
- Qt5Quick.dll
- Qt5Sensors.dll
- Qt5OpenGL.dll

Ok, I can understand why it wants `Qt5Multimedia.dll`. Browser can play sound etc. But `QML`!  Why I need all these libraries related to `QML`?? I don't use neither `OpenGL` nor sensors or positioning. So it's just unnecessary in my case.

And so my question - is there way to deploy only libraries I need in actual fact? And get the program work of course.

Comment: If you are not interested in the DLL linking because you have a GPL (not LGPL) software anyways, you might consider statically linking QT

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `windeployqt.exe`.

From the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html):

> The Windows deployment tool can be found in QTDIR/bin/windeployqt. It
>   is designed to automate the process of creating a deployable folder
>   that contains all libraries, QML imports, plugins, translations that
>   are required to run the application from that folder. This is used to
>   create the sandbox for Windows Runtime or an installation tree for
>   Windows desktop applications that can be easily bundled by an
>   installer.

This is how I do:

```
cd [my program dir]
mkdir RELEASE
cd RELEASE
copy ..\"progname.exe" .
set QTDIR=C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\mingw491_32\bin
call %QTDIR%\qtenv2.bat
windeployqt --force "progname.exe"
```

You could adapt that for your need by changing `[my program dir]`  to your application's folder (containing the `.exe` file), `QTDIR` to your Qt MinGW folder (that's what I use) and `progname.exe` with the name of your executable file.

It will create a `release` directory with your executable and the needed Qt libraries (.dll's, etc).

Comment: I don't use windeploy due to its limitation and short-sighted search. For example -  from some reason, windeploy copied all dll in sqldrivers although i use only pgpsql. But anyway - I have no problem with libraries assembling. My problem is that Qt wants some unnecessary dlls. As I said - QWebView doesn't work without Qt5Qml.dll and Qt5Quick.dll but I don't use QML at all in my program